# When I put FileUpload inside update panel it does not appear in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

The file upload does not appear when I put it inside update panel. I need to add it inside update panel because FileUpload.HasFile Always returns false

my html code :

```
   <tr>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
    <td>
       <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"   
         Text="Upload" />
                    </td>
               <asp:FileUpload ID="FUCivilID" runat="server" />
          <asp:Image ID="imgViewFile" runat="server" Height="60px"  
                     Width="275px" />
                </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1_Click" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>      
     </tr>
```

upload button code :

```
if (FUCivilID.HasFile) 
{
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(FUCivilID.FileName);
   if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif")
   { 
      imgViewFile.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/CivilIds/" + FUCivilID.FileName);
      FUCivilID.SaveAs(MapPath("~/CivilIds/" + FUCivilID.FileName));
      imgViewFile.ImageUrl = "~/CivilIds/" + FUCivilID.FileName;
   }
```

In page load :

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Comment: Google when used properly can yield amazing results.. 
[MSDN asp:UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fileUpload control has some problems with the updatePanel ([Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)), try to change your

```
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1_Click" EventName="Click" />
```

for a

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1_Click" EventName="Click" />
```

> To use a FileUpload or HtmlInputFile control inside an UpdatePanel
>   control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a
>   PostBackTrigger control for the panel. The FileUpload and
>   HtmlInputFile control can be used only in postback scenarios.

Also there are another alternatives, I have used [FUA](http://en.fileuploadajax.subgurim.net/empezar.aspx) successfully

Comment: it's return an error in event name not valid attributes in element  PostBackTrigger please can you told me how to solve FileUpload.HasFile Always returns false without using the update panel or even if I have to use update panel how to make it work